# Use dynamic finders with list of Object IDs

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails3

With the given class structure

```
class MyObject {
   Status status;
}

class Status {
   Integer id;
}
```

I want to use dynamic finders to query based on a list of Status ID values.  What I want to be able to do is something like this

`MyObject.findAllByStatusInList([1,2,3]);`

This does not work though because my list needs to be `Status` objects.  I know I can build a criteria to do this, but I just want to know if there is a way to accomplish this with Dynamic Finders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *where* clause:

```
MyObject.where {status.id in [1,2,3]}.find()
```

**UPD**

Dynamic finders don't support aliasing so Criteria (or DetachedCriteria) is the solution to be used.

In case if *Status* class is a domain entity you could retrieve a list of them (or load their proxies) from the database and then query *MyObject*s by the status list.

So I see no other appropriate solution but using *Criteria* in your case.

Comment: Thanks for that, but that is essentially a criteria built query which I mentioned already know about.  I am specifically looking for a way to do this with the dynamic finder API.  If it is not possible then please note that in your answer.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin updated the answer. Why are you avoiding Criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You can still accomplish this using the dynamic finder.

```
def statuses = [1, 2, 3].collect { Status.load(it) }
MyObject.findAllByStatusInList(statuses)
```

[`load()`](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html) will create a proxy for you that won't require retrieving the instance from the database as long as you don't access any properties other than `id`.

Comment: Do the dynamic finders query always by the object ID?  Meaning if I have overloaded the `equals()` or implemented `Comparable` does that have any effect if `load()` only pulls the `id`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

`List`**`<`**`Integer > statuses = [1, 2, 3]`
`MyObject.findAllByStatusInList(statuses)`